# When do records commit to database in Salesforce

Tags: order-of-execution

All ,

I have a question on order of executions.  I understand, the order of execution 
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

I am facing a issue here. Let's say ,I have a field Field__c , it has previous values "abc" .I update value with "XYZ" in the before trigger. In short, trigger.old has abd and trigger.new has XYZ. Process continues "After" triggers runs and then workflow. In workflow , I update the same record which fires the trigger again . **Now , what will be the value in trigger.old and trigger.new ??**

Comment: The answer is at the bottom of the page you yourself referred to. "For example, suppose an existing record has a number field with an initial value of 1. A user updates this field to 10, and a workflow rule field update fires and increments it to 11. In the update trigger that fires after the workflow field update, the field value of the object obtained from Trigger.old is the original value of 1, rather than 10, as would typically be the case."

Comment: Thanks Lex.  When record does get updated and get value 1 in before trigger.